# Methods are being randomly called when space bar is pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm having a super creepy problem. When space bar is pressed, one out of the three methods in a script will be called randomly. Those methods should only be called when button UIs are pressed. The only space bar input I have in the project is in another script, with no way it should be able to call those methods.

The script with the three methods (skillOne, Two, Three)

```
    IEnumerator pause()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.75f);   
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    }

    private void SetSkill(int skillNumber)
    {
        chosenSkill = skillNumber;
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        animator.SetTrigger("Out");
        shoot.enabled = true;
        Cursor.SetCursor(cursor, Vector2.zero, CursorMode.Auto);
        enabled = false;
    }
    void Start()
    {
        shoot = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Shoot>();
        icon = iconPlaceholder.GetComponent<Image>();
        shoot.enabled = false;
        Cursor.SetCursor(defaultcursor, Vector2.zero, CursorMode.Auto);
        StartCoroutine(pause());
    }

    public void SkillOne()
    {
        SetSkill(1);
        icon.sprite = sentry;
        Debug.Log("debug");
    }

    public void SkillTwo()
    {
        SetSkill(2);
        icon.sprite = aegis;
        Debug.Log("debug");
    }

    public void SkillThree()
    {
        SetSkill(3);
        icon.sprite = davids;
        Debug.Log("debug");
    }
```

The only code that contains space input

```
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && Time.time - lastTimePressed >= cooldown)
        {
            audioManager.PlaySFX(audioManager.accel);
            ChangeSpeed();
        }

        if (speedChanged && Time.time - speedChangeTime >= yourTimeThreshold)
        {
            RevertSpeed();
        }

        if(speedChanged == true)
        {
            Instantiate(trailPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        }

        if(speedChanged == false)
        {
            Destroy(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameController"));
        }
```

Yes it is ugly, I'm new to Unity.

I tested and know that the methods are not called when I changed the space input to something else, but they still react when space is pressed. I tried disabling the whole script, but didn't worked, the methods are still being called.

Comment: If those conditions are exclusive, then simply replace `if` with `else if` (starting from second `if`). See [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_conditions_elseif.php).

Comment: also, space can press a button if its focused

Comment: What is `ChangeSpeed()`?

Comment: I suspect @BugFinder is correct, one of your buttons has focus and spacebar is assigned as the submit button.  You can remove spacebar from the submit button from the Edit>Project Settings>Input Manager>Submit (binding is called `space` in Alt Positive Button).

Comment: @hijinxbassist You're right! I worked perfectly fine after I disabled that key bind, thank you guys so much!

Comment: @Jay ChangeSpeed() is just a method that changes the player's speed value to run faster.